# Avoid blocking UI rendering while api fetching data, React

Tags: reactjs, performance

I am working on React app which fetches large data (Thousands of records) and then render it. Until api is fetching data, UI keep blocked and does not display anything. I am **creating chunks** in size of 10 for fetching api using **Promise.allSettled** and combining them all.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchBatchedData()
 },[])
```

`fetchBatchedData` is an async function and **sets data in redux store only, I don`t need that data in UI at loading time**. Until I get all the data, UI display nothing. How can I fetch data in background without blocking component rendering?

Comment: Have you tried [webworker](https://medium.com/hackernoon/web-workers-in-react-redux-application-129274e84a4e) for async fetch?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a useState like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = () => {
        const tempData = fetchBatchedData();
        setData(tempData)
    }
 },[])

if(!data){
  return(
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  )
} else {
  return(
    <h1>Got the data!</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: No this is not the issue. Issue is render blocking not the displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can defer rendering the data? There is something called `requestIdleCallback` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback).

Something like this maybe?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function RenderDeferred({ children, timeout }) {
  const [render, setRender] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (render) setRender(false);
    const id = requestIdleCallback(() => setRender(true), { timeout: idleTimeout });

    return () => cancelIdleCallback(id);
   }, [idleTimeout]);

  if (!render) return null;

  return children;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<RenderDeferred timeout={3000}>
    <YourComponent />
</RenderDeferred>
```